# 2D BoundingBox Collision Detection Problem

Tags: java, libgdx

I implemented collision detection into my game (using Bounding Boxes) The character is floating above the blocks instead of standing on them. I know what is happening, but I can't figure out how to calculate how high that space is, so I can change the position.

Here is a picture:
[image: The character is floating in the air]

Comment: I don't know libgdx, but if you are calculating through any built-in bounding box method then double check the actual canvas of your images. May be your player's or that box's image have some extra empty transparent area in actual image.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the boundingbox size (you should), the character position would be:

```
character.y=floorBoundingBox.y - characterBoundingBox.height
```

You don't actually directly calculate the *difference* between the floor and the character, you calculate the position of colliding objects by pushing them their height or width outside the floor.

Comment: But this is only if the character stands on top of the blocks, if he is coming from below it would be another formula, right?

Comment: It is similar. Basically you calculate the 'overlap' of the two boxes, you pick the largest value (horizontal or vertical) and push the non static object out into that direction by the overlap size.

Comment: @Felsir that would be the smallest value, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Ugh, you are correct. Smallest value is the correct value.